# Download FTP directory and files in remote Ubuntu server via SSH

Tags: server, ssh, ftp, wget

I want to download the files listed in a FTP directory, ftp://ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/NAMA3DS1_COSPAD1/Avi_videos/HRC_00_Reference/. On my WINDOWS laptop when I put this link in the address bar of file explorer, I am able to view and download its content as shown below,

[image]

But I want to download these files in a remote UBUNTU server via ssh and have tried the following with corresponding error message,

1. Both `wget -r ftp://ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/NAMA3DS1_COSPAD1/Avi_videos/HRC_00_Reference/` and `wget -m ftp://ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/NAMA3DS1_COSPAD1/Avi_videos/HRC_00_Reference/` gives the following error

```
--2021-08-24 09:18:07--  ftp://ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/NAMA3DS1_COSPAD1/Avi_videos/HRC_00_Reference/
           => ‘ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/NAMA3DS1_COSPAD1/Avi_videos/HRC_00_Reference/.listing’
Resolving ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr (ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr)... 193.52.82.2
Connecting to ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr (ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr)|193.52.82.2|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ...
Error in server response, closing control connection.
Retrying.
```

A more detailed error report using `wget -r -v -d ftp://ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/NAMA3DS1_COSPAD1/Avi_videos/HRC_00_Reference/`  gives the following error report,

```
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.17.1 on linux-gnu.
Reading HSTS entries from /usr2/mohilamb/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Using ‘ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/NAMA3DS1_COSPAD1/Avi_videos/HRC_00_Reference/.listing’ as listing tmp file.
--2021-08-24 15:13:32--  ftp://ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/NAMA3DS1_COSPAD1/Avi_videos/HRC_00_Reference/
           => ‘ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/NAMA3DS1_COSPAD1/Avi_videos/HRC_00_Reference/.listing’
Resolving ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr (ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr)... 193.52.82.2
Caching ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr => 193.52.82.2
Connecting to ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr (ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr)|193.52.82.2|:21... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x00005608710e8320 (new refcount 1).
220 FTP server ready
Logging in as anonymous ...
--> USER anonymous


Error in server response, closing control connection.
Closed fd 3
Retrying.

--2021-08-24 15:13:34--  ftp://ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/NAMA3DS1_COSPAD1/Avi_videos/HRC_00_Reference/
  (try: 2) => ‘ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr/NAMA3DS1_COSPAD1/Avi_videos/HRC_00_Reference/.listing’
Found ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr in host_name_addresses_map (0x5608710e8320)
Connecting to ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr (ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr)|193.52.82.2|:21... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x00005608710e8320 (new refcount 1).
220 FTP server ready
Logging in as anonymous ...
--> USER anonymous


Error in server response, closing control connection.
Closed fd 3
Retrying.
```

2. I even tried ftp and sftp and they also do not work.

Interestingly if I execute it on Google Colab I am able to download the ftp directory. But for my remote Ubuntu system I get the above-mentioned errors. Note that one does not require username or password to access it.

Comment: It is possible that the FTP server may restrict the IP addresses from which login is allowed. Or your Ubuntu server may be behind a firewall that restricts FTP traffic. On my home Ubuntu computer, I was able to execute your `wget` command successfully, so it looks to me more like a networking issue.

Answer (score 1):

If ssh is enabled, and you know the path then it should be simple to do from either of the hosts.

scp username@myhost.com:/ftp_root_folder/NAMA3DS1_COSPAD1/Avi_videos/HRC_00_Reference/*.* /home/someUser/DestinationFolder/

If scp is not available.

```
ftp
open ftp.ivc.polytech.univ-nantes.fr
cd /NAMA3DS1_COSPAD1/Avi_videos/HRC_00_Reference/
lcd ~/MyLocalPath/
pull *
```

I just tried this on your host, and it worked
You might need to enable passive mode with pasv

Comment: Did you actually try to login to the host where the OP wanted to run the command (how? he didn't give us neither IP address nor credentials) and tried **from there**? Because the problem seems to be FTP connection failing **from that particular machine**...

Comment: @Ben As i have already mentioned in the question, the ftp command you suggest does not work on my remote Ubuntu. I agree with Raj that seems to be a firewall issue. But how to detect this and want changes should i make to enable this.